# Getting just the first part of a string before a certain symbol

Tags: javascript

If I have a string that looks something like this: "A, A - Email: BLAH@BLAH.COM" and wanted to just get the part of the string BEFORE the " -" (space included), how would I go about that using Javascript?  To clarify, I want to get just "A, A" from that string above.  I've read about substrings and splits, but they seem to just return the string AFTER the symbol indicated (I could be wrong on that), and also the part of the string I want is of variable length so I can't just use numbers to indicate where I want to cut the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "A, A - Email: BLAH@BLAH.COM";
$pos = $string.indexOf('-'); //gives you the numeric index of the symbol
$youneed = $string.substr(0, $pos); //creates a new string starting from the beginning if string, up till the specified position (position of '-')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `indexOf` to find the `-` in the string and then `substring` to get the string starting from `0` up to that index.

```
var s = "A, A - Email: BLAH@BLAH.COM";
var idx = s.indexOf(" -");
var t = s.substring(0,idx);
```